# How to use std::pow in std::transform as the unary function?

Tags: c++, std, pow

I'm trying to write a function that returns the n-th norm of a vector where n in the input to the function.

```
double n_norm = N_Norm(std::vector< double > x, double n);
```

I'm trying to use std::transform method and std::pow to calculate the n-th power of all the elements in the input vector.

```
return (std::pow(std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), std::bind2nd(std::pow<double>(), n)), 1/n));
```

But I get this error:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::pow" matches the argument list.

Anyone knows how I can fix my unary function?

Comment: Don't use `std::bind2nd`. It was removed from the standard. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12

Comment: switching to bind1st didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Don't use `std::bind1st` either. It was removed from the standard. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12

Comment: `std::transform()` returns an iterator. Why are you calling `std::pow()` on the iterator returned by `std::transform()`? `std::pow()` cannot accept that as an argument - which the compiler points out to you in the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Justin Can you tell me what to use instead?

Comment: @PlinyTheElder It populates the n-th power of x vector values back into the vector.

Comment: No it doesn't. The error you are seeing is because `std::pow()` does not have an overload that can accept an iterator.

Comment: Use lambda instead of `std::bind*`: `[n](double d) { return std::pow(d, n);}`.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42! I think it did the trick! :)

Comment: @Jarod42 OP's problem is not with lambda, though.

Comment: @SergeyA:Partially, as its bind was incorrect: `std::bind2nd(std::pow<double>(), n)` with extra parents, instead of `std::bind2nd(&std::pow<double>, n)`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you wanted to write:

```
double N_Norm(std::vector<double> v, double n)
{
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), [n](double d) { std::pow(d, n); });
    double sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.);
    return std::pow(sum, 1 / n);
}
```

But that do extra copy of the vector.

In c++17, you may do:

```
double N_Norm(std::vector<double> v, double n)
{
    return std::pow(std::transform_reduce(v.begin(),
                                          v.end(),
                                          0.,
                                          std::plus<>{},
                                          [n](double d){ return std::pow(d, n); }),
                    1 / n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::transform` doesn't fit here. You should use `std::accumulate`.
Also since C++11 you have lambdas which are much more handy then `std::bind1st` or `std::bind2d` or `std::bind`.

```
double N_NormAcc(const std::vector< double > &v, double n) {
    auto sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, [n](auto sum, auto x) { 
        return sum + std::pow(std::fabs(x), n);
    });
    return std::pow(sum, 1.0 / n);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/yhJIZrMcgNT9GznF

Comment: sorry, :/ fixed